# How do I get `gem` working again after upgrading to rubygems 1.8.x?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Soooo, I upgraded to RubyGems 1.8.1 from 1.7.2 using `gem upgrade --system`, then immediately ran `gem pristine --all --no-extensions` as recommended on [Eric Hodel's blog](http://blog.segment7.net/2011/05/04/rubygems-1-8-0). After getting errors when running `gem` commands, I googled around a bit, found some suggestions to `gem uninstall` the gems with the deprecation warnings, but then realized I can't, as `gem uninstall` just errors out--as does any other command--including just plain ol' `gem`.

When I run any of those commands, I get a bunch of "deprecated" warnings still, then this backtrace:

```
/Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:277:in `block in _resort!': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:276:in `sort!'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:276:in `_resort!'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:270:in `_all'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:402:in `each'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:477:in `map'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:477:in `find_files'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1061:in `load_plugins'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:85:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem:9:in `<main>'
```

The same thing happened when I tried this again, but upgrading from RubyGems 1.6.2, using the same update command.  I tried a 3rd time, but instead used the suggestion below to do `gem install rubygems-update && update_rubygems`--that just resulted in a failed install, and kept me with a usable RubyGems 1.6.2.

I'd like to a) use RubyGems 1.8.x, and b) undo these changes as opposed to having to blow away my 1.9.2 install *again*.
Any ideas?  I'm running:

- rvm 1.6.5
- MRI 1.9.2

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 180) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/sloveless/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/sloveless/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/sloveless/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
     - /Users/sloveless/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org
```

FWIW, there was a similar bug logged in the RubyGems bug repo just today (May 10), and I added similar info to that, [here](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29196&group_id=126&atid=575)

Comment: What does `which gem` tell you?

Comment: `/Users/sloveless/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem`

Comment: Thank you so much for this - I had to re-install and ended up with a new version of rubygems, and everything was messed up. This helps!

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem with gems 1.{7..8}.*.

Here's our production stack:

- MRI 1.9.2 and JRuby 1.6.1
- RVM 1.6.5
- **Gems 1.6.2**

Stay away from upgrading gems itself, or shit may break.  I know how tempting it is to use bleeding edge, but it's more like profusely hemorrhaging all over the O.R. walls.

If you must:

- Current user only (more common): `gem install rubygems-update -v 1.6.2 && update_rubygems`
- System-wide (caution): `sudo gem install rubygems-update -v 1.6.2 && sudo update_rubygems`

If using RVM, be sure to `rvm gemset global` first.

Usual caveats apply such as backup your data, gemsets, apps and don't try this in production. :)

Comment: Thanks... I downgraded to 1.6.2, and life is better now. I used this command: "gem update --system 1.6.2"

Comment: Great analogy there.  :)  FWIW, I gave upgrading a try using the `rubygems-update` method you suggested, and that fails too--the nice thing is, though, that I'm left with a usable `gem` command, unlike with the other method.  I guess I'm stuck on 1.6.2 for now...

Comment: One of my machines is running 1.3.7, and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for figuring out which version works.

Comment: FWIW, things seem pretty stable up till 1.6.2.  I've had pretty good success with 1.7.2, but people at work haven't shared that success and are still holding at 1.6.2.

Comment: Downgrading is good advice, at least for now. See this bug report for more details... and please leave a supportive comment if you want my patch to be accepted. https://rubyforge.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=575&aid=29176&group_id=126

Comment: Dredging up an old thread: I think ruby gems has their act more together now.  Upgrade with caution in a test environment yadayada.

Answer (score 0):

It's not tied to RVM, as I'm running the same version. It's not Ruby 1.9.2 either, again because I'm running the same version.

`gem uninstall ...` returning errors isn't normal. I've done the upgrade on several machines running RVM and 1.9.2 and gem itself continued running correctly. And, yes, I saw the deprecated warnings.

Is it possibly you ran `gem update` using `sudo`? That would probably break it since you're running under RVM, and sudo is a major no-no.

Comment: Interesting.  I figured it wasn't normal, as I didn't find anyone else saying anything similar.  I'm sure I didn't run using `sudo`--I've used RVM for so long that I'm totally out of that habit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well...  I encountered the same error as you after updating rubygems and doing `gem pristine --all --no-extensions`.  I, on the other hand, didn't understand the major no-no about doing my gem installs and updates using sudo, so I have a whole other mess to clean up.  However, this is how I got back to a working installation:

I updated rvm by doing a fresh install:  http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

I encountered some other permissions issues with this step due to my no-no sudo'ing ways, but got past it.  I did have to open a new terminal session for the changes to work.

Then, `$ rvm rubygems current` as described here: http://beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/

This installed version 1.6.2.  So far, I seem to have a working `gem` command again, and my deprecation warnings are gone.  Hope it helps.